# Evaluate the limit : $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f\left(\frac{3}{2}(3+\sqrt{7})^n\right)}{g\left(\frac{1}{2}(2+\sqrt{2})^n\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, binomial-theorem, periodic-functions

Let $f:R\to R$ and $g:R\to R$ be periodic functions with period $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ respectively such that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}=2$$
then evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f\left(\frac{3}{2}(3+\sqrt{7})^n\right)}{g\left(\frac{1}{2}(2+\sqrt{2})^n\right)}$$

**My Attempt**

I assumed $f(x)=\frac{3}{4\pi}\sin\left(\frac{4\pi x}{3}\right)$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(4\pi x)$ and got answer as $0$. Could there be a better way to do it

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Should the powers not be $-n$ in stead of $n$?

Comment: @Math-fun No. It is $n$

Comment: I see: but the information given on $f$ and $g$ describe their behavior in the vicinity of $x=0$ not when $x \to \infty$ [which the question seems to be about]. This makes putting together an asnwer sort of impossible.

Comment: Consider the number $3/2[(3-\sqrt{7})^n+(3+\sqrt{7})^n]$ for $f$. And a similar number for $g$

Comment: Your particular examples are with bounded periodic functions but you do have examples with not-bounded functions like $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan(2\pi x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{3}{\pi}\tan(\frac{2\pi x}{3})$

Comment: @Piquito But domain is given to be $R$

Comment: @Maverick: Domain of a function can be distinct of the starting set (frenchs call "application" when the domain of a function is the starting set by definition)

Comment: @Maverick: Maybe you are right according to american way. I don't know. Regards.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Please give a more detailed explanation. I used this fact to evaluate the limit using the two assumed functions

Comment: In evaluating the limit using your assumed functions, you must have used the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}=1$. Well, you know similar limits for $f$ and $g$, so you could just as well have avoided making the said assumption.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269729/911563
Similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use specific examples for $f, g$. Instead you need to use the properties of $f, g$ given in question.

Let $$a=(3+\sqrt {7})^n,b=(3-\sqrt {7})^n,c=a+b$$ and $$p=(2+\sqrt {2})^n,q=(2-\sqrt{2})^n,r=p+q$$ so that $a, b, c, p, q, r$ are variables depending on $n$.

Let us note that $c, r$ are positive integers (via binomial theorem) and $b, q$ tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty $. The expression under limit can be written as $$\frac {f(3a/2)}{g(p/2)}=\frac{f(3c/2-3b/2)}{g(r/2-q/2)}$$ and by periodic nature of $f, g$ the above expression equals $$\frac {f(-3b/2)}{g(-q/2)}=\frac{f(-3b/2)/(-3b/2)}{g(-q/2)/(-q/2)}\cdot\frac {3b} {q} $$ The first fraction tends to $1/2$ and hence the limit in question is equal to the limit of $3b/2q$.

Now $$\frac{b} {q} =\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{7}}{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\to 0$$ and hence desired limit is $0$.